# Is this possible to send and store emails inside a list and map the email fields inside the list fields?

Tags: 2013, list, development, incoming-email, smtp

I am working on SharePoint server 2013. and we want to have the ability for users to send suggestions by email and get these emails saved inside a SharePoint list. now i know that each list can have an in-coming email settings, where you can basically send emails to a list. but i have these questions before start working on this:-

1. can i map the email fields mainly the email's "From","Subject" & "Body" fields into the list fields.. by saying for example that the email "From" field should be saved inside a site column named "EmailFrom"??
2. In addition to mapping these fields , can i save the original email as an attachment inside the list item? so when user send an email to a list the email got saved as an attachment inside the list item?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can grab the mail headers using an Event Handler. This will fire when an email is received.

   public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, String receiverData) 
   {
       SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();
       newItem["EmailFrom"] = emailMessage.Headers["From"]
       newItem["EmailTo"] = emailMessage.Headers["To"]
       // etc, etc....
       newItem.Update(); 
   }

See here: https://jasear.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/enable-incoming-emails-on-a-custom-sharepoint-list/

2. Yes, attachments can be saved also. If they're failing, check out the following.

See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx#section6

Comment: my second question is not about saving the attachment , but rahter saving the original email as an attachment inside the list items..

Comment: You can do the same within the Event Receiver. Save the body text as an attachment. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334695/sharepoint-how-to-add-an-attachment-to-a-list-item-programatically

Comment: thanks for your very helpful explanation .. so can you adivce if this scenario is achievable in SharePoint 2013. Let say a user will send an email to the list, then can i do the following mapping between the email and the list item :- map the email title to be equal to the list item title. map the email body to be equal to the list item Description field. map the email sender to be equal to the list item created by. add the original email as an attachment inside the list item. add any attachments inside the email as an attachment to the list item ????

Comment: Yes. All of that is feasible. You just need custom code in an event receiver to pull it off.

Comment: Now i did a test where i added an announcement list and i configure the in-coming email for it. Then i send an email to the list, where i got the following mapping out-of-the-box.1) email sender = item createdBy. 2) email body = item body. 3) email cc = item CC field. 4) the original email (including attachment) will be attached to the item....

Comment: But the only thing i did not get is that if the email contain an attachment (eg. MS word) then this word document will not get attached to the list item. so is there a way to achieve this ? currently if i want to view the word document , i need to do this through the .eml link ... where i have to click on the .eml link , save/open the email , then i can view the attachments..